# in angularjs, how do you get a `select` to refresh when the array for ng-options changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

have an `select` based on any array.  the elements in the array may change.  how do I get the angular controller to refresh the array?

#### module.js

```
var langMod = angular.module('langMod', []);
langMod.controller( .controller( 'colorCntl', function($scope) {
  $scope.color = 'wt';
  $scope.colorArr = [
    { id: 'br', name: 'brown' },
    { id: 'wt', name: 'white' }
  ];
});
```

#### index.html

```
<form ng-controller='wordCntl' >
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in colorArr">
     <option value=''>-- chose color --</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

#### from the console:

```
> scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('select')).scope();
> scope.colorArr.push( { id:'bk', name:'black' } );
  3
note! the select dropdown still only has brown and white, not black
```

how do I get the `select` to refresh so that all elements in `colorArr` are options?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Angular uses [watchers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch), and will only update the UI if a [digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$digest) has been kicked off.

Normally you would be adding to the array via some event in the UI, or by calling the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), and those take care of kicking off a [$digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$digest) for you.

Since you are just adding directly to the array, Angular does not know anything has changed, and therefore does not update the UI.

Wrap your statement inside of a `scope.$apply(function(){ //code });` instead.

Comment: @josh is it possible to refresh the select list without using the `scope.$apply`?

Comment: @starcorn - Any update that occurs within a digest loop is going to update automatically. You only need to call `scope.$apply` when you do something outside of Angular's knowledge. For instance, if you are using a 3rd party Ajax library (jQuery), or an event that wasn't triggered by an Angular directive.