# How to update select on array change in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my problem: I need to pull a list of Timezones using an API call to populate a select element on the page. What's the proper angularjs way of doing this? I've tried:

HTML:

```
<select class="custom-select timezone" name="Timezone" id="Timezone" ng-model="regCtrl.user.Timezone" ng-options="timezone.DisplayName for timezone in regCtrl.Timezones></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('RegisterController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.Timezones = [];
    $http.get('/User/GetTimezones').success(function (result) { 
        $scope.Timezones = result;
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:
It is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872387/in-angularjs-how-do-you-get-a-select-to-refresh-when-the-array-for-ng-options?lq=1) - I've tried that and it didn't help. The error must be in syntax somehow. If I'm not right, and this is a duplicate of the above question, could someone please show me by example how to apply that fix to my code. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please link the duplicate of my question, because if you think of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872387/in-angularjs-how-do-you-get-a-select-to-refresh-when-the-array-for-ng-options?lq=1) - I've tried that and it does not apply to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove controller name in you html

```
<select class="custom-select timezone" name="Timezone" id="Timezone" ng-model="user.Timezone" ng-options="timezone.DisplayName for timezone in Timezones></select>
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping the code in an answer, would you care to explain what you changed, and why it should work?

Comment: Exactly - You've changed ng-model, which was working fine to begin with. The problem I have is caused by updating the array with a callback function and html not updating automatically after that. When I set the list on the start it all works fine.