# Angular - Select fields don't update when value received via $http

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have two select fields, one for Month and one for Day (controller as name is 'contactDetails'):

```
<select
  data-ng-model="contactDetails.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth"
  data-ng-options="bdMonth.key as bdMonth.value for bdMonth in contactDetails.months">
  <option value="">Month</option>
</select>
<select
  data-ng-model="contactDetails.contactBasicInfo.bdday"
  data-ng-options="bdDay.key as bdDay.value for bdDay in contactDetails.days">
  <option value="">Day</option>
</select>
```

That output the selects just fine and I can use them to save information to the database. No problems there.
The issue is when I pull the info back out of the database and want the select fields to update to reflect the values pulled from the database. They don't. If I hard-code the values into the controller, they'll update, but not if the values are assigned after an $http call.

I have this at the top of the controller to set up the defaults:

```
ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth = 0;
ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdday = 0;
```

And later I call a function that then assigns values to those two variables:

```
ctrl.contactBasicInfo = data.contactInfo.contactBasicInfo;
```

All other data that comes out of `data.contactInfo.contactBasicInfo` works and the fields update, like firstName, phone, email, etc. If I place the models in the html like `{{ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth}}`, it will show the correct values. So, I know the values are coming back correctly from the $http call. The selects just don't change to reflect the new values.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872387/in-angularjs-how-do-you-get-a-select-to-refresh-when-the-array-for-ng-options

Comment: Would using `track by` help in this instance?

Comment: @JanR I don't think we're talking about the same thing. The array that builds the select never changes, only the selected value does.

Comment: @Lex I'm not sure how `track by` would help here. The select does update if I write a new value into the code to replace the default 0. So, it would seem the two-way binding is working fine. I just don't know why it's not detecting the new value from the $http return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the directive `ngModel` for a `<select>` element uses the `===` comparison when binding. Hence `0 === '0'` will return false. So you should assign a string not a number/integer to your `ngModel` attached to the dropdown.

Comment: So, what value do I use for day of the month other than a number? As I said, if I change the =0 to =3 for the default bdmonth value, the select will change to March. But if the http returns and sets the value to 3, it does nothing. So numbers for the values do work, right? Or are you saying I just need to put quotes around the number?

Comment: Use the javascript toString() function on your integer returned by the $http call.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Still not working. I set `ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth = data.contactInfo.contactBasicInfoBD.bdmonth.toString();` Still doesn't change the select. But if I do this: `ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth = 3;` the select changes. And that's a number 3 and not a string 3. However, this does NOT work: `ctrl.contactBasicInfo.bdmonth = '3';` So I don't think it's a matter of having the number be a string. At least it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Ah okay. I see. I also needed to change the numbers that build the select values to strings. '3' instead of 3. Thanks!